# Django restapi passing parameter to read()

Tags: python, django

In the test example http://django-rest-interface.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/django_restapi_tests/examples/custom_urls.py on line 19 to they parse the request.path to get the poll_id. This looks very fragile to me. If the url changes then this line breaks. I have attempted to pass in the poll_id but this did not work. 
   So my question is how do I use the poll_id (or any other value) gathered from the url?

Comment: You've got a typo in your URL: s/cooclecode/googlecode/

Comment: Please define "did not work".  Did you get errors because of unexpected arguments to read() or did you get some other errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are only called when the associated url is matched. By crafting the url regex properly, you can guarantee that any request passed to your view will have the `poll_id` at the correct position in the request path. This is what the example does:

```
url(r'^json/polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/choices/$', json_choice_resource, {'is_entry':False}),
```

The `json_choice_resource` view is an instance of `django_restapi.model_resource.Collection` and thus the `read()` method of `Collection` will only ever act on requests with paths of the expected format.

Comment: So if I understandyou correctly the split only works on the portion of the url that is in the calling url.py file. <br>So if the url is http://SomeHost.com/json/polls/5/choices/ or http://SomeHost.com/SomeSystem/json/polls/5/choices/ the split("/") will resolve the same because the host portion of the url is in another url.py file?

Comment: That is correct. If you want the full path relative to the domain, you need to use request.get_full_path()